# arrays as global variables in sinatra

Tags: ruby, database, sinatra

Hello i would like to have arrays store something then i access it to fill some data in the database, i would like to know how to do this, and also how to declare them as global, you may explain using the code below

I want to use the arrays to store some data, then put that data in the database, but i seen not to be able to do that: I am using DataMapper also

the two post method have to access those global arrays that is what i need to figure out. thanks ( I am  sinatra newbie)

```
module Scanner
  class SellItemApp < Scanner::Base

    configure do
      set :in_customer,[] #to be used in adding multiple items
      set :items, [] #to be used in adding multiple items
    end

    get '/something' do
      erb :sale_records
    end

    post '/something1' do
      .........
    end

    post 'something2' do
    .....

    end

  end
end
```

Comment: You should be more specific in what you want to do inside `post '/something'`, otherwise it is hard to help.

Comment: What's the scope you want to keep these lists in? session, user, cache, forever...?

Comment: @UriAgassi I just need to keep these arrays available for as long they are still being used by the post methods

Comment: i'd also like to know more about global variable in sinatra if you can direct me i'd be grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration is meant for *static* data, which is not changed in the life of the application, and *not* part of its state.

Using configuration to cache data between requests is not a good idea for several reasons:

- Global data is not insulated - when a user adds an 'item' in your app *all* other users will see it, since it is stored globally...
- In-memory data is not scalable - this solution *might* work as long as you run a single sinatra instance on a single machine. At the moment your application needs to scale, either by adding machines, or even by using multiple processes (in a `passenger` or `unicorn` containers) - data changes in one process/machine is not populated to other processes/machines - and it won't be consistent.
- Not thread safe - even if you scale by making you application multi-threaded, you'll just be entering the world of pain of race-conditions and synchronization blocks
- It is not persistent - if your process fails for some reason - all of its state is lost.

So, what *should* you do? There are a couple of options, depending on your requirements - should the data for shared by all users, or insulated between users? Should it be persistent over time?

- If the data is in the scope of the user, and should be kept only for the current session, you can use `cookies` to save your data, using Sinatra's [`sessions`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#sessions)
- If the data is global, should be kept for availability, but if data is lost it is not a catastrophe - you can use [`memcached`](https://gist.github.com/mralex/956592)
- If the data should be kept for a long time, you should seriously consider persisting it. It doesn't *have* to be mapped by `ActiveRecord` or `DataMapper`, depending on the complexity of your data. It doesn't even have to be persisted to a relational database like `mysql`, some noSql options like [`redis`](https://github.com/bmizerany/sinatra-redis), [`couchbase`](http://www.couchbase.com/), etc. can be easily added to your ruby project.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand Leonard correctly he wants to access some "configuration" variables he intends to use as makeshift database. Quoting from the [Sinatra documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html) there is

```
set :foo, 'bar'
set :baz, Proc.new { "Hello " + foo }

get '/baz' do
  "baz is set to " + settings.baz
end
```

and I *guess* (have not tried it) you might stuff your things into it if you like. Note however that this will be lost if you restart your server (should carry over for multiple requests though).

If you want your "stored data" to survive a server restart `DataMapper` is of course the right solution. See the corresponding docs on how to do it. It is probably not a good idea to use a *configuration* mechanism for any kind of data "storage".